# multiple end of file $'s in a single file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I copy pasted some enum values from my IntelliJ IDE in windows to notepad, saved the file in a shared drive, then opened it up in a linux box. When I did `cat -A` on the file it showed something like:

```
A,B,C,^M$
D,E,F,^M$
G,H,I,^M$
```

After searching around I figured that ^M is the carriage return and $ means the last line of the file. I'm just puzzled at how this file is able to have multiple $'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is the end of line marker with `cat -A`, not end of file.

This is indicating the file has Windows-style line endings (carriage return followed by line feed) and not Unix-style (only line feed).

(You can convert text files from one format to the other using the programs `dos2unix` or `unix2dos`.)

Comment: Ah yes! is there a way to match windows style line endings with sed? I've tried `sed 's/\r\n//` with no luck

Comment: With sed the EOL character '\n' isn't considered part of the line (some regex engines have a "single line mode" which considers the entire input as one line, but not sed AFAIK). If you want to match '\r\n' you could do '\r$' instead, which matches '\r' at the end of the line (and so is equivalent). One fun fact is that a terminal will actually interpret '\r' as "go back to start of line" (which was its original meaning), so if you do sed 's/$/.../' on '\r\n' you end up with '...' overwriting each line. A line like "hello\r\n" would become "hello\r...\n" so the terminal ends up writing "...lo".

Comment: That clears away my confusion. I was wondering why it was so complicated to match \n with sed (snip - `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`). The \r fact is very interesting, I suspect this originated from the typewriter era(?). Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

From `man cat` on my GNU box:

```
   -A, --show-all
          equivalent to -vET
```

(snip)

```
   -E, --show-ends
          display $ at end of each line
```

Thus, there are multiple `$`s because there are multiple lines, each with an end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's what I get for not reading the man pages more carefully. I wish I could accept both answers, since Porges tied it down with windows/linux line feed differences I'll select his answer. Thanks again for your input! :)

Comment: Well, I'm obviously somewhat biased, but your actual question was "why do I have multiple $s"; you answered the carriage return bit yourself ;P I jest though, meanwhile, glad you're sorted, and yes, `man` is an invaluable tool!

Comment: Oh I really wish we were allowed to select both answers (although that would a a bit weird).